# How to find the inverse of a stereographic projection of a sphere

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider a sphere $S = {(x, y, z) ∈ R^3 | x^2 + y^2 + (z − 1)^2 = 1}$ and the North Pole is (0,0,2). And $(u,v) = p(x,y,x)$ where p is the stereographic projection function.

Verify that the inverse of its stereographic projection is:

$x =
\frac{4u}
{u^2+v^2+4}$ ,
$y =
\frac{4v}
{u^2+v^2+4}$ ,
$z =
\frac{2(u^2+v^2)} 
{u^2+v^2+4}$

I understood what a stereographic projection mean but still I can't seem to be able to think of where do I begin to verify each one of the components of its inverse. Any help or tip would be very much appreciated.

Comment: A maybe more preferable coordinate-free version here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4016091/stereographic-projection-of-unit-sphere-in-a-banach-space/4016146#4016146

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line defined by $(0,0,2)$ and $(u,v,0)$ consists of the points of the form$$(tu,tv,2-2t),\tag1$$with $t\in\Bbb R$. Such a point belongs to $S$ if and only if$$(tu)^2+(tv)^2+(1-2t)^2=1\tag2$$and $t\ne 0$ (if $t=0$, we get the point $(0,0,2)$). The other solution of $(2)$ is $t=\frac4{u^2+v^2+4}$. And, with this $t$, $(1)$ becomes$$\left(\frac{4u}{u^2+v^2+4},\frac{4v}{u^2+v^2+4},\frac{2u^2+2v^2}{u^2+v^2+4}\right).$$